# Stop cron from emailing me

Tags: unix

How can I stop cron from emailing me the results of jobs I schedule?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By setting the environment variable "MAILTO" as ""

Somethig like:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
MAILTO=



01 * * * *  /your/path/to/script/here.sh
```

Comment: This didn't work for SpamAssassin `/etc/cron.d/sa-update`. It still emailed me the errors.

Comment: on macos `MAILTO=` is rejected by `crontab` but `MAILTO=""` worked fine.

Answer (score 14):

If you want a single job to stop email you simply append >/dev/null 2>&1 to it

For example:

```
0 * * * * /home/script >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: If you are sure that one run will finish before the next starts, it can be worth redirecting the output to a named file rather than to /dev/null: that does give the option of checking what happened to the last run if you suspect a problem.

Answer (score 6):

Cron only emails you if there is output, either on `stdout` or `stderr`.

If it's script you've written, make it less verbose - remove unnecessary `echo` or `print` statements. Redirecting `stdout` to `/dev/null` is also a valid solution:

```
2 * * * * /my/script > /dev/null
```

If you still get messages after doing that, then the output is on `stderr`, thus it *should* be an error, which you should resolve.. If not, you can redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` with..

```
2 * * * * /my/script > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

..although disregarding error messages is generally a bad idea! (How will you know when the cron job is broken?)

You could redirect a specific command's output from stderr to stdout using `2>&1` - for example:

```
command_which_prints_messages_to_stderr 2>&1 # redirect stderr to stdout
```

..then direct `stdout` to `/dev/null` in your cron job - that way you silence the loud command, without losing error messages