# Why does terminal say: "You have mail"?

Tags: macos, email, terminal, notifications

Any idea why my Mac terminal says:

> You have mail in /var/mail/lofye

How can I make it stop saying that every time I open terminal?

Comment: Best answers are available here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2432/16253

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Somehow you've had a script or something similar deliver mail to your account on your local machine which is stored in `/var/mail/$USER`

You can either remove the file `/var/mail/$USER` which will remove the alert that you have mail (as it will alert you if that folder is present and/or has unread messages) or you can use `mail` to read the messages before deleting them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Turns out a CRON is mailing me... 36,061 times :( Deleted with command:  d 1-36061

Comment: See this question.  http://superuser.com/questions/7677/stop-cron-from-emailing-me

Comment: You can direct the cron output to /dev/null to avoid the mail.

Comment: Where is this default text located on Mac OS X? I'd like to leave it active but change the message.

Comment: How can I disable only notifications without losing emails?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1728/
Funny because it's true :)

Comment: Cron is so cute with this little mails <3

Answer (score 55):

Type `mail` to view the mail. I believe `d` deletes it.

Comment: * d should delete everything.

Comment: When using mailx d* will delete everything. Mail itself won't.

Comment: Doing `mail` and then `d *` removed all mails for me on Mac OS X.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28745/how-do-i-delete-all-terminal-mail to delete all messages.

Comment: This answer did not work for me. Thanks to @ShaunDychko's link, I found the reason: Make sure do to exit with `q` after the `d *` command, only that saves the changes to disk.

Answer (score 17):

There are several ways to remove it. The simplest is:

```
> /var/mail/<whatever_user>
```

You need to include the '>'

Comment: That **wipes out** the received mail for that user.

Answer (score 6):

Open `mail` and then put in `d *` and press Enter. The `d` command means `delete` and the `*` selects all mails in the list.

Answer (score 2):

I'm willing to bet it's because there are files in that folder.

Have you actually looked at the contents of the folder? If there is something in there, it will more than likely give you an idea of what caused it, and how to prevent it in the future.

From the terminal:

```
cd /var/mail/lofye
ls
```

If you don't have mail, you won't see the message (there's not even a folder for my username under mail on my mac).

Comment: `/var/mail` is a directory, and `loyfe` is the file within it. To view the file, one could `less /var/mail/loyfe`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running ClamAV for Mac this is a known issue. The system mails you after each update and scheduled scan.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick way.

1. completely empty the email file

> : > /var/mail/$User

2. change the attribute of email file

> sudo chflags schg /var/mail/$User

As except "root", no one can change this file.

Then the annoying "You have mail" gone away.

Answer (score -3):

I was able to just create a .hushlogin and I've a clean Terminal now.

```
$ touch .hushlogin
```

Comment: This prevents many messages from being displayed, not just the new mail message. This could be dangerous as there are certain other warnings the user would miss out on.