# How can I prevent the "You have mail." message from displaying every time I open the Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, email, terminal

Every time I open the Terminal, I get the "You have mail." message, but I do not have any mail. When I run MAIL it reads, "No mail for myusername". I have tried several methods to prevent this from occurring every time I use the Terminal, including adding unset MAILCHECK to my bash profile.

Comment: Try adding the following line to your ~/.bashrc unset MAILCHECK

Comment: Read your mail. *runs*

Comment: see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2432/4667 and http://superuser.com/q/25738/4714

Comment: yep, check /var/mail/username, as suggested by the above links; maybe something go stuck there

Comment: just checked, even having empty directory /var/mail/username results in "you have mail", deleting the 'username' directory in /var/mail fixes this

Comment: @maxskybarger -- if there is something in /var/mail/username indeed, you may want to look at the contents and figure out what has sent it; a lot of *nix software sends all sorts of emails by default, you may want to turn that off

Comment: Thanks for the clue. There were two blank lines in  /var/mail/username and removing them solved the problem.

Comment: Please answer the question yourself so you can mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 7):

**From the comments on the question:**

check `/var/mail/<username>`

There were two blank lines in `/var/mail/<username>` and removing them solved the problem.

Also, deleting the `<username>` directory in `/var/mail` will fix this.